Почему не работает роутинг сайта при использовании более одного элемента url пути
Я только начинаю программировать сайты и у меня возникли проблемы с роутингом сайта, с основными ссылками работает всё нормально(http://site/catalog и так далее), но проблемы возникают с более длинными url (http://site/about/contact), можете подсказать в чём проблема
<?php
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$segments = explode('/', trim($uri, '/'));

switch ($segments[0]) {
    case 'about':
        if($segments[1] === ''){
            require 'pages/about/about.php';
        }
        else{
            $file = 'pages/about/' . $segments[1] . '.php';
        
            if(file_exists($file))
                require $file;
            else
                require 'pages/404.php';
        }
        break;
    
    default:
        if($segments[0] === ''){
            require 'pages/main.php';
        }
        else{
            $file = 'pages/' . $segments[0] . '.php';
    
            if(file_exists($file))
                require $file;
            else
                require 'pages/404.php';
        }
        break;
}



как задать хороший вопрос. начать можно с более внятной формулировки заголовка

Функция file_exists в качестве входного параметра принимает полный путь до файла, а не относительный от корневой директории сайта.
